# Include these variables into cmake

Tags: cmake

This scientific application I am using uses cmake to build its program. Attached is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(PROJECT_NAME myproject)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

# Set verbose output while testing CMake
#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)

# Set CMake behavior
cmake_policy(SET CMP0004 OLD)

# Get DOLFIN configuration data (DOLFINConfig.cmake must be in
# DOLFIN_CMAKE_CONFIG_PATH)
find_package(DOLFIN)

# Need to get VTK config because VTK uses advanced VTK features which
# mean it's not enough to just link to the DOLFIN target. See
# http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtk-developers/2013-October/014402.html
find_package(VTK HINTS ${VTK_DIR} $ENV{VTK_DIR} NO_MODULE QUIET)

# Default build type (can be overridden by user)
if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RelWithDebInfo" CACHE STRING
    "Choose the type of build, options are: Debug MinSizeRel Release RelWithDebInfo." FORCE)
endif()

# Compiler definitions
add_definitions(${DOLFIN_CXX_DEFINITIONS})

# Compiler flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${DOLFIN_CXX_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

# Include directories
include_directories(${DOLFIN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(SYSTEM ${DOLFIN_3RD_PARTY_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# Target libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${DOLFIN_LIBRARIES})
```

However, I need to include some additional compiler flags and libraries not included within DOLFIN. I need to incorporate this package called PAPI. On my system, the paths/environments are:

```
PAPI_LIBDIR=/project/cacds/apps/papi/5.4.0/lib
PAPI_INCLUDE=/project/cacds/apps/papi/5.4.0/include
PAPI_FLAG=-lpapi
```

Normally I would do something like this:

```
gcc -O3 -o -I myproject $(PAPI_LIBDIR) main.c -L $(PAPI_INCLUDE) $(PAPI_FLAG)
```

But again I need the additional DOLFIN libraries and third party packages. Pardon me if this is a silly or simple question, but how would I modify the above CMakeLists.txt? I am kind of new to cmake, so any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleanest solution would be to create a `FindPAPI.cmake`. So, add to your project this file inside of a `cmake/`folder:

***FindPAPI.cmake***

```
# Try to find PAPI headers and libraries.
#
# Usage of this module as follows:
#
#     find_package(PAPI)
#
# Variables used by this module, they can change the default behaviour and need
# to be set before calling find_package:
#
#  PAPI_PREFIX         Set this variable to the root installation of
#                      libpapi if the module has problems finding the
#                      proper installation path.
#
# Variables defined by this module:
#
#  PAPI_FOUND              System has PAPI libraries and headers
#  PAPI_LIBRARIES          The PAPI library
#  PAPI_INCLUDE_DIRS       The location of PAPI headers

find_path(PAPI_PREFIX
    NAMES include/papi.h
)

find_library(PAPI_LIBRARIES
    # Pick the static library first for easier run-time linking.
    NAMES libpapi.a papi
    HINTS ${PAPI_PREFIX}/lib ${HILTIDEPS}/lib
)

find_path(PAPI_INCLUDE_DIRS
    NAMES papi.h
    HINTS ${PAPI_PREFIX}/include ${HILTIDEPS}/include
)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(PAPI DEFAULT_MSG
    PAPI_LIBRARIES
    PAPI_INCLUDE_DIRS
)

mark_as_advanced(
    PAPI_PREFIX_DIRS
    PAPI_LIBRARIES
    PAPI_INCLUDE_DIRS
)
```

Then, modify your CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(PROJECT_NAME myproject)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH};${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(PAPI REQUIRED)

...

# Include directories
include_directories(${DOLFIN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(SYSTEM ${DOLFIN_3RD_PARTY_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${PAPI_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# Target libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PAPI_LIBRARIES} ${DOLFIN_LIBRARIES})
```

I hope it resolves it! ;)